# How I can bind keys for selecting language directly in Lubuntu 13.10?

Tags: shortcut-keys, lubuntu, keyboard-layout, language-support

I like to change keyboard bindings **directly** to language that I want to use. I use the following keyboard bindings to change keyboard layout in OS Windows7:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for Russian, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for Polish, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> for French, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> for Ukrainian, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> for Lithuanian etc.

How I can configure Lubuntu 13.10 for doing the same? I've found how to change keyboard layout choosing languages cyclically (Alt+shift, for example), but like to select needed language layout directly using specific combination of keys for each language.

Direct language selection is possible in Windows 7, may be it is possible also in Lubuntu?

Comment: You connaissez слишком talen, freund!  ;)
Unfortunately, there is no way to do *exactly* in Ubuntu as you have in Windows...  There *is* more then one way to kill a bear though...